# How do i count this loop?

Tags: loops, count

I don't get this loop why is the output 52

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int k=3, tot=0;
while (k<11)
{    tot=tot+k;
  k++; 
} 
System.out.print(tot); 
}
}
```

Comment: 3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 52. If you find it confusing, then dump out the value of the various variables at each iteration of the loop. e.g. print out `k`, `tot` and see how they're changing.

Answer (score 2):

What happens:

It loops eight times (11 - 3), since at each iteration `k` is incremented

- `tot = 0 + 3`
- `tot = 3 + 4`
- `tot = 7 + 5`
- `tot = 12 + 6`
- `tot = 18 + 7`
- `tot = 25 + 8`
- `tot = 33 + 9`
- `tot = 42 + 10`